# How do I write the <<<TOC  thing in PHP?

Tags: php, string, heredoc

I forgot how to write the one command that looked something like this

```
<<TOC


bla bla

bal bal


TOC;
```

how was it written again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP expression <<<EOB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048481/php-expression-eob)

Answer (score 8):

These are called [heredocs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Answer (score 2):

It works like this:

```
$foo = <<<TOKEN
multi
line
string
TOKEN;
```

`TOKEN` can be anything you want as long as you being and end the heredoc with the same exact thing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is corect syntax for using a heredoc, however make sure that TOC; line is not indented or it will not work. FYI you can call it anything you want such as HTML not just TOC.

Answer (score 2):

Good Examples:

```
$foo = <<<TOKEN⁋
multi⁋
line⁋
string⁋
TOKEN;⁋
```

However, these don't work

```
$foo = <<<TOKEN‧anything here⁋
multi⁋
line⁋
string⁋
TOKEN;‧anything here⁋
```

```
$foo = <<<TOKEN
multi⁋
line⁋
string⁋
‧TOKEN;
```

```
$foo = <<<TOKEN
multi⁋
line⁋
string⁋
→TOKEN;
```

The closing token must be on its own line, hard up against the left margin, followed directly with its following semi colon, followed directly with a carriage return.